# Rails 4 serialized hash is not being updated in database, but INSERT statement is shown in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to update a Hash in a Rails 4 model, which is serialized. I've looked into the logs, and I found the INSERT statements with the data, but when I tried to retrieve it later I found the data didn't persist to the database. My code looks like this:

```
dol = DolTestResult.new
dol.results = {}
# ...
dol.save
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because I didn't put a bang at the end of `save` that it didn't work. Changing it to `dol.save!` didn't work.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, is there a typo in your statement?

Comment: Not a typo, but an error in calling the method. I should have called `save!` instead of `save`, because the latter only returns the modified object.